# PHP remove portion of a string by pattern

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

i have bunch of strings, where i need cut out one portion:

```
1. Adaptation of a one-step worst-case optimal univariate algorithm of bi-objective Lipschitz optimization to multidimensional problems, vol. 21 [looked: 2014 m. september 15 d.], p. 89-98.
2. On benchmarking stochastic global optimization algorithms, 2014 [looked 2014 m. spetember 17 d.], p. 9-12.
3. Quadratic programming with complementarity constraints for multidimensional scaling with city-block distances, Vol. 2, no. 4 [looked 2014 m. december 05 d.], p. 248-259.
```

and many others. I need remove [looked *YYYY* m. *month dd* d.] portion. Which begins with "[looked" and ends with "]".
How can i achieve this?

i have tried preg_replace, but i cannot build up great working pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this,

```
preg_replace('~\[Looked\b[^\]]*\]~', '', $str);
```

Comment: add `\s*` before the first `\[` , if you want to remove also the leading spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
preg_replace("/\[looked(.+?)\]/","",$str)
```